# ignore values in PHP array when using foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this array of items:

```
$TicketStatuses = array('Customer Reply' => '#F36F25', 'Needs Action' => '#FF0000', 'Open' => '#999999', 'On Hold' => '#666666');
```

then sometimes i am calling it but there is no need for the hex codes.

**for example:**

```
foreach ($TicketStatuses as $status) {
    echo $status.'<br>';
}
```

but its showing the hex codes rather than the names. is there anyway i can ignore the second values for each item in the array?

Comment: What you need is known as array keys.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (array_keys($TicketStatuses) as $status) {
    echo $status.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: why you use **array_keys()**? Function will pass the entire array, which will affect the performance of large arrays.

Comment: As far as I could tell from the OP's original question, they wanted all the keys, not a subset of the keys, so that's what I provided a solution for..... your own solution is working with the entire array as well, and also has a big performance hit.... perhaps you'd care to measure to see which solution is most efficient

Comment: Stumbled upon this and wanted to clarify; the performance of both answers is actually the same. Remember, PHP is a copy-on-write language so values are only copied if you change them, so there's no cost to having keys and values in a loop when you don't use both. Meanwhile `array_keys` is actually optimised away since it's only being iterated, so actually the opcode for both answers is basically the same. So the "best" solution is down to personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($TicketStatuses as $key => $status) {
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```